# migrate multiple database user table in single table issue

Tags: database-migration

`login User table` in multiple database migrate to one single table. How to manage old records. because all `user id` can be changed. records are mismatching. what is the best solution for that ??

For example
`adminuser_id = 4` after migration `adminuser_id=100`

The old records of admin records are saved link table with `admin_id=4`
but current id is 100.how to retrieve old records in link table.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Identity in the ID column,
I would suggest on adding another OLD_ID column which is not unique 
And constrain both old_id and id as the table keys.
You know which user came from which table so you can add a bit of logic behind the scene.
But its really tricky in general to merge Identity tables and keeping the data the same.

Comment: any other way for this problem?